# Extra newline coming from somewhere

Tags: awk, gawk

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to do it better.

I have a file consisting of records with field separator "-" and record separator "\t" (tab). I want to put each record on a line, followed by the line number, separated by a tab. The input file is called `foo.txt`.

```
$ cat foo.txt
a-b-c   e-f-g   x-y-z
$ < foo.txt tr -cd "\t" | wc -c
2
$ wc foo.txt
 1  3 18 foo.txt
```

My awk script is in the file `foo.awk`

```
BEGIN { RS = "\t" ; FS = "-" ; OFS = "\t" }
{
    print $1 "-" $2 "-" $3, NR
}
```

And here is what I get when I run it:

```
$ gawk -f foo.awk foo.txt
a-b-c   1
e-f-g   2
x-y-z
    3
```

The last record is directly followed by a newline, a tab, and the last number. What is going on?

Comment: Pipe the output of your `awk` through `cat -vet` to see. `awk ... | cat -vet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I don't know your exact goal, but since you have built the thing with awk, you can just add `\n` to `FS` to reach your goal to remove the trailing `\n` and without starting another process, like `tr, sed or awk`

```
BEGIN { RS = "\t" ; FS = "-|\n" ; OFS = "\t" }
```

Comment: Yes, that is a nice solution.

Comment: What I was doing was a bit more involved (filter some records depending on the value in one of the fields), and it seems that the easiest would have probably been to first make all tabs into new lines and then invoke awk on it. Thank you for the explanation and the hint.

Answer (score 1):

There is an newline character at the end of your data that is also output when printing `$3`.

In particular, it looks like this:

```
$1 = "x"
$2 = "y"
$3 = "z\n"
```

You can remove the trailing separator with `tr` before passing everything to `awk`:

```
 tr -d '\n' < foo.txt | awk -f foo.awk
```

or alternatively add `\n` to the list of field separators (as shown in the answer by Kent), since `awk` will strip any separators from the fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "\t"; FS = OFS = "-" } { sub(/\n/, ""); print $0 "\t" NR }' file
```

Output:

```
a-b-c   1
e-f-g   2
x-y-z   3
```

- `ORS = "\n"` was not necessary.

And with GNU Awk or Mawk, you can just have `RS = "[\t\n]+"`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "[\t\n]+"; FS = OFS = "-" } { print $0 "\t" NR }' file
```